# Quoted variables in shell script

Tags: macos, variables

I'm attempting to determine if the Auto Proxy URL on a Mac as been configured.
First, I want to get the port number

```
port=$(route get example.com | grep interface | sed 's/.*\(...\)/\1/')
```

Then use the port number to obtain the active network service

```
service=$(networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep $port |  sed 's/,.*$//; s/^.*: //')
```

And finally, I use the active network service to obtain the auto proxy info

```
autoproxy=$(networksetup -getautoproxyurl \"$service\")
```

I'm running into a problem with any network service that includes spaces.  For example **Wi-Fi** works fine, but **Apple USB Ethernet Adapter** does not.
I thought the solution would be to escape the quotes (\"$service\")
The odd thing is that if I echo $service (where $service is **Apple USB Ethernet Adapter**) it returns a properly quoted result of "Apple USB Ethernet Adapter"  If I then copy and paste this exact result as a replacement for the variable $service, I get the result I was expecting (**URL: (null) Enabled: No**)
However, running the command as it was originally written returns a parameter error (**Error: The parameters were not valid**).

This is the result of running the script as is:

```
 autoproxy=$(networksetup -getautoproxyurl "$service")
 echo $autoproxy
 Error: The parameters were not valid.
```

However, if I copy and paste the output of $service, then it returns the result I was expecting.

```
service=$(networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep $port |  sed 's/,.*$//; s/^.*: //')
echo \"$service\"
"Apple USB Ethernet Adapter"
autoproxy=$(networksetup -getautoproxyurl "Apple USB Ethernet Adapter")
echo $autoproxy
URL: (null) Enabled: No
```

Comment: `autoproxy=$(networksetup -getautoproxyurl "$service")` *should* work, if `$service` is set correctly. Try using `set -x` before running these commands, and see what it outputs. Warning: the output can be somewhat misleading because it prints something equivalent to the command being executed. For instance, with your version with escaped quotes it'll print `++ networksetup -getautoproxyurl '"Apple' USB Ethernet 'Adapter"'` -- the single-quotes are added to indicate that the double-quotes are being treated as part of the arguments, rather than going around a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "" for service variable in autoproxy expression.